# Auth0 Logout always redirects to first url from Allowed Logout URLs

Tags: reactjs, auth0, auth0-connection

I have a React application, and whenever I do logout, it always redirects to first URL from “Allowed Logout URLs” even though I have specified the returnTo in my provider.

Here’s the code for my provider:

```
<Auth0Provider
            domain="<My domain here>"
            clientId="<My clientId here>"
            authorizationParams={{
                redirect_uri: window.location.origin + window.location.pathname,
                audience: '<My audience here>',
                scope: 'openid profile email',
            }}
            logoutParams={{
                returnTo: 'http://localhost:3000/logout',
            }}
        >
```

So, let’s say my application is located at `https://example.com`. I have mentioned `https://localhost:3000/logout, https://example.com/logout` in the `Allowed Logout URLs` list for my application on Auth0. I have also mentioned them on the advanced settings on my Tenant level.

I have also tried to provide `returnTo` while calling `logout` like below:

```
const { logout } = useAuth0();
logout({ returnTo: window.location.origin });
```

I am planning to use different Auth0 tenant for differnet environments going forward, but for now we just have a single tenant between dev and staging envs.

I have already looked at Auth0 community but no success so far. For example - https://community.auth0.com/t/auth0-allowed-logout-urls-only-working-with-1st-url-in-the-list/113002

Still, whenever I do logout when I am on `https://example.com`, it redirects me to `https://localhost:3000/logout` since thats the first URL in the list.

How to redirect users to `https://example.com/logout` instead of the localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of statically `returnTo` URL in the Auth0Provider component, try setting it dynamically based on the current environment, Like that:

```
<Auth0Provider
  domain="<My domain here>"
  clientId="<My clientId here>"
  authorizationParams={{
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin + window.location.pathname,
    audience: '<My audience here>',
    scope: 'openid profile email',
  }}
  logoutParams={{
    returnTo: window.location.origin + '/logout',
  }}
>
```

Comment: I have done that as well, but it doesn't seem to work.